# Create a list of lists from a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list of dictionaries that I am wanting to convert to a nested list with the first element of that list(lst[0]) containing the dictionary keys and the rest of the elements of the list containing values for each dictionary.

```
[{'id': '123',
  'name': 'bob',
  'city': 'LA'},
 {'id': '321',
  'name': 'sally',
  'city': 'manhattan'},
 {'id': '125',
  'name': 'fred',
  'city': 'miami'}]
```

My expected output result is:

```
[['id','name','city'], ['123','bob','LA'],['321','sally','manhattan'],['125','fred','miami']]
```

What would be a way to go about this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything?

Comment: answer has already been provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
d = [{'id': '123',
  'name': 'bob',
  'city': 'LA'},
 {'id': '321',
  'name': 'sally',
  'city': 'manhattan'},
 {'id': '125',
  'name': 'fred',
  'city': 'miami'}]
[[k for k in d[0].keys()], *[list(i.values()) for i in d ]]
```

output:

```
[['id', 'name', 'city'],
 ['123', 'bob', 'LA'],
 ['321', 'sally', 'manhattan'],
 ['125', 'fred', 'miami']]
```

first, you get a list with your keys then get a list with the values for every inner `dict`

Comment: Note: This suggestion assumes that the `dict`s were constructed in the same way, such that the key/value pairs iterate in the same order in all `dict`s (which won't be true in the case of bucket collisions where the `dict`s are constructed with keys inserted in different orders, or other subtle issues that can easily occur in all but the strict literal case shown in the OP's question).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = [{'id': '123',
  'name': 'bob',
  'city': 'LA'},
 {'id': '321',
  'name': 'sally',
  'city': 'manhattan'},
 {'id': '125',
  'name': 'fred',
  'city': 'miami'}]
>>> [list(x[0].keys())]+[list(i.values()) for i in d]
[['id', 'name', 'city'], ['123', 'bob', 'LA'], ['321', 'sally', 'manhattan'], ['125', 'fred', 'miami']]
```

Comment: Note: This suggestion assumes that the `dict`s were constructed in the same way, such that the key/value pairs iterate in the same order in all `dict`s (which won't be true in the case of bucket collisions where the `dict`s are constructed with keys inserted in different orders, or other subtle issues that can easily occur in all but the strict literal case shown in the OP's question).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  The dictionary keys always appear in the same order.  So this answer should meet my needs if that is the case, correct?  Trying to make sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @acodejdatam: Yes, it will work if all `dict`s are constructed the same way, with the keys inserted in the same order. On CPython/PyPy 3.6+ (any Python 3.7+) you'll get consistent ordering if your insertions are also consistently ordered the same way; on prior versions of Python, the ordering could vary from run to run (due to per-run hash seed), but as long as insertions are in the same order, the relative indexes of keys and their values will be consistent within a run (so `'id'` could be at any index in its `list`, but the values associated with it will be at the same relative index).

Comment: @acodejdatam: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60642697/364696) will have the same issue with ordering varying from run to run prior to 3.6 (`'id'` might come before or after `'name'`), but no matter how the `dict`s are constructed (same key insertion order or not), the index of each key in the first sub`list` will always match the index of all the associated values in the other sub`list`s.

Answer (score 1):

Serious suggestion: To avoid the possibility of some `dict`s having a different iteration order, base the order off the first entry and [use `operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get a consistent order from all entries efficiently:

```
import operator

d = [{'id': '123',
  'name': 'bob',
  'city': 'LA'},
 {'id': '321',
  'name': 'sally',
  'city': 'manhattan'},
 {'id': '125',
  'name': 'fred',
  'city': 'miami'}]

keys = list(d[0])
keygetter = operator.itemgetter(*keys)
result = [keys, *[list(keygetter(x)) for x in d]]  # [keys, *map(list, map(keygetter, d))] might be a titch faster
```

If a `list` of `tuple`s is acceptable, this is simpler/faster:

```
keys = tuple(d[0])
keygetter = operator.itemgetter(*keys)
result = [keys, *map(keygetter, d)]
```

---

Unserious suggestion: Let [`csv` do it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for you!

```
import csv
import io

dicts = [{'id': '123',
  'name': 'bob',
  'city': 'LA'},
 {'id': '321',
  'name': 'sally',
  'city': 'manhattan'},
 {'id': '125',
  'name': 'fred',
  'city': 'miami'}]

with io.StringIO() as sio:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(sio, dicts[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(dicts)
    sio.seek(0)
    result = list(csv.reader(sio))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9BS8QwEIXv@RVzSwJL2LZ4WfAgeBEEDx48LHvIttEO2yYlGS1F9rfXaaNg9ZTJm/fNzBsmaoOv5hn7IUSCOn2I7xKDEA3WlOAWjp8SG3kAWZSV3AkA6W3vFuEczlmokaZFeLyTVxZ@gKostkCyXTdtkd761hJZvyGL8mZLvkbX/AHR9iivJyFGpJYvNs8U0b89PCkNNkHCcGA/wBiRXOQgnM/cc6iXVVBs2MEa8rg/mYubktL6F2HWp3W2YfP/RgxjUiueezzOJOcuap//0aX3jnhth4nUsjvmUWzUeh74VlLZpOcv)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with for loop and [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in method.

```
listOfDicts = [
    {"id": "123", "name": "bob", "city": "LA"},
    {"id": "321", "name": "sally", "city": "manhattan"},
    {"id": "125", "name": "fred", "city": "miami"},
]

results = []
for index, dic in enumerate(listOfDicts, start = 0):
    if index == 0:
        results.append(list(dic.keys()))
        results.append(list(dic.values()))
    else:
        results.append(list(dic.values()))

print(results)
```

output:

```
[['id', 'name', 'city'], ['123', 'bob', 'LA'], ['321', 'sally', 'manhattan'], ['125', 'fred', 'miami']]
```

Comment: You could remove the need for `enumerate` entirely by just changing the initializer of `results` to `results = [list(listOfDicts[0])]`, so only values need to be appended in the future. This will have the same construction ordering issues that [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642469/create-a-list-of-lists-from-a-dictionary-python/60642697#comment107289135_60642498) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642469/create-a-list-of-lists-from-a-dictionary-python/60642697#comment107289136_60642510) on two other answers.